# The implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0' cant resolve

Tags: android, calendarview

why my material calendar view failed to resolve, here is my 
Module: app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.cms"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0'

}
```

here is my BUILD FILE

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

when I sync the gradle the error showed is

> Failed to resolve:
>   com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0

open.dependency.in.project.structure affected module app
Please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an issue in your **dependency version**

```
implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0'
```

**Replace with**

```
implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this code:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

in the `settings.gradle`